# Load XML into MySQL (Label and Value)

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have an XML file to load into MySQL, but it is generated with a label and a value instead of being fully qualified.

So instead of

```
<book>
<name>Lord of the Flies</name>
<author>William Golding</author>
</book>
<book>
<name>War and Peace</name>
<author>Leo Tolstoy</author>
</book>
```

It is like

```
<book>
<label>name</label>
<value>Lord of the Flies</value>
<label>author</label>
<value>William Golding</value>
</book>
<book>
<label>name</label>
<value>War and Peace</value>
<label>author</label>
<value>Leo Tolstoy</value>
</book>
```

My code so far is -

book as $mybooks) {

    $label=$mybooks->Label;
    $value=$mybooks->Value;

    echo "$label - $value";
    }
    }
    ?>

The output then is

```
Lord of the Flies - William Golding
War and Peace - Leo Tolstoy
```

Problem is that this does not have a reference to the field name which I can use to map it in my MySQL table.

What would be the best way to go about reading these into variables to push into a MySQL table (fields - name, author) using PHP?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data using...

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$xml = <<< XML
<books>
<book>
<label>name</label>
<value>Lord of the Flies</value>
<label>author</label>
<value>William Golding</value>
</book>
<book>
<label>name</label>
<value>War and Peace</value>
<label>author</label>
<value>Leo Tolstoy</value>
</book>
</books>
XML;

$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ( $doc->book as $book )   {
    echo $book->label[0]."=".$book->value[0]."\n";
    echo $book->label[1]."=".$book->value[1]."\n";
}
```

I've wrapped the book elements into a top level XML element to make it a valid document.

This is loaded using simplexml and then the foreach simply iterates over the books.

The labels and values will be an array in each element, so label[0] is for value[0].  You can use count($book->label) to work out how many elements there are.

The above code will output...

```
name=Lord of the Flies
author=William Golding
name=War and Peace
author=Leo Tolstoy
```